# Financial timestamp to date object

Tags: r, datetime

I have a chr variable in formats:

```
20160101 000000
20160101 235600
```

which I want to convert to:

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00
2016-01-01 23:56:00
```

I can convert the date easily with:

```
as.Date('20160101 000000', format="%Y%m%d")
```

but that only converts the date. So I wonder if there is a function that can do both.
Cheers

Update:
Per suggestion of David Arenburg I use:

```
as.POSIXct('20160101 000000', format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
```

and this solves my problem.

Comment: `as.Date` is not the correct function if you want to include time too, see `?as.POSIXct`. You also haven't specified time arguments in your `format` so not sure what do you expect. Finally, the specific case of midnight won't display the time argument even if you''ll specify everything correctly -  this is by design

Comment: @DavidArenburg Ok I have updated the question and will try with POSIXct. Not sure if midnight will be a problem since it never gets to 24:00:00

Comment: It will. You have it in your own example. Compare `as.POSIXct("20160101 000000", format = "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")` with `as.POSIXct("20160101 235600", format = "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")`. Eitherway, please check out `?strptime` for more information regarding `Date` formats in R.

Comment: Yup you are correct :-) Thanks.

Comment: @DavidArenburg it seems as it does not print out to console however in Dataframe everything looks correct.

Comment: yes, it's only a display issues (like I said in my initial comment).